# How to set live click function on last element of class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As in title, want to set "click" function on last element of class

```
$("#someID .someClass:last").live("click", function () {
            $('#someID').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: `:last` should work. Just curious which version of jQuery you are using as `live` is depercated

Comment: Live is deprecated. You should also use Google. https://api.jquery.com/live/, http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/, http://api.jquery.com/last/.

Comment: whether the elements are added dynamically?

Comment: last should indeed work.
http://jsfiddle.net/AtpLM/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9. You should use `.on`:

```
$("#someID").on("click", ".someClass:last-child", function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** was deprecated as of version `1.7` and removed in version `1.9`, you should use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead.

If your element has been added dynamically, you can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here:

```
$("#someID").on("click", ".someClass:last-child" function () {
    $('#someID').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.live()`  method deprecated in jQuery 1.7. You should use `.on` method. [See Doc.](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#someID .someClass:last').on('click',function() {
   $('#someID').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

**Fiddle demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hq4SL/

Answer (score 0):

`.live` was deprecated in favour of `.on`. Try this:

```
$("#someID").on("click", ".someClass:last-child" function () {
  $('#someID').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about live. It is deprecated. You should use on instead. Try this:

```
$('#someID').on('click', .'someClass:last', function () {
        $(this).animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
        return false;
});
```

Comment: You should use the delegation syntax to emulate what `.live()` does.